# Can file encoding change when FTP is used?

Tags: linux, ftp, content-encoding

I'm developing a web application which downloads a number of web pages using PHP curl. It then uses `diff` to compare the files as they change each day.

I reported a problem a few weeks back where seemingly identical files were being flagged by `diff` as being different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552239/different-versions-of-diff-giving-mixed-results-when-comparing-2-identical-fil

The answer to the above was that if `diff` was used with the `-w` flag it ignores whitespace.

However, I've now noticed a separate problem. If I download one of the files I'm comparing, and re-upload (overwrite) it through an FTP client, the output changes.

For example: Compare `file1.html` against `file2.html` with `diff file1.html file2.html` it may give output such as

```
12159,12161c12159,12161
<   
< 
< 
---
>   
> 
> 
12163,12172c12163,12172
< 
< 
< 
< 
< 
< 
< 
< 
< 
< 
---
```

However, if I download `file2.html` to my desktop and re-upload it through FTP, `diff` **without the `-w` flag** reports there being no differences at all i.e. it's now saying the files are identical.

I've tried to check the encoding of the file using `file -bi file2.html` but it's reported the same before and after upload through FTP. The encoding is `text/html; charset=us-ascii`

If the encoding is no different and the file contents have not been modified, how is re-uploading the file through FTP changing anything?? I've tried it using FileZilla and also through Netbeans.

I'm using macOS Sierra locally and the remote server is Apache 2/PHP 7/centOS.

Comment: Obligatory security note: [FTP is totally insecure](http://www.raditha.com/php/ftp/security.php). Consider your FTP passwords and any files on the server as compromised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably seeing a difference in line-endings. When transferring a file in ASCII/Text mode (as opposed to "Binary mode") then most FTP clients will convert/normalise line-endings to the OS being transferred to.

On Classic Mac OS (9.x and earlier) the line-ending char is simply `\r` (ASCII 13), on Mac OS X this changed to `\n` (ASCII 10), on Linux it is `\n` (ASCII 10). And Windows is `\r\n` or ASCII 13+10. (Thanks @8bittree for the Mac correction.)

So, when downloading from one OS to another all line-endings are silently converted. The conversion is reversed when uploaded. (However, as noted in [@Joshua's answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/104644/1243) this can result in corruption, depending on the file's character encoding and specific characters contained in the file.) If there is a mishmash of line-endings then it's possible the FTP software is normalising/fixing the line-endings. This would explain why downloading and then uploading the file results in a "different" file to what was originally on the server (ie. it is "fixed"). Or it is reverting a previously miss-converted file? However, the EOL-conversion may not be so intelligent and you can just end up with either double spaced lines or missing line breaks altogether (ie. mildly corrupted).

By default, most FTP clients are set to "Auto" transfer mode and have a list of known file types to transfer in ASCII/Text mode. Other file types are transferred in "Binary" mode. If you are transferring between the same OS, or you wish to transfer with no conversion, then you should use "Binary" mode only.

Ordinarily, the FTP software will not change the character encoding of the transferred file unless the source/target operating systems use a very different character encoding with which to represent text files. As @KeithDavies noted in comments, one such example is when downloading from a mainframe, that uses [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), to a local Windows machine. EBCDIC is not supported natively by Windows, so a conversion is required to convert this to ASCII. Again, transferring in "Binary mode" avoids any such conversion. (Thanks to @KeithDavies for the note regarding character encoding.)

> The answer to the above was that if diff was used with the -w flag it ignores whitespace.

Yes, line-endings (whitespace) are ignored in the comparison.

> If I download one of the files I'm comparing, and re-upload (overwrite) it through an FTP client, the output changes.

If there was a mixture of line-endings in the original file then downloading and re-uploading in ASCII mode could well "fix" the inconsistent line-endings. So, the files are now "the same".

Comment: this is really interesting, and thank you for the information. However, the problem is the *opposite* of what you've stated as far as it affects my application. The files are marked as being identical when compared in `diff` *after* they are re-uploaded via FTP. *before* the FTP stage occurs they are considered different by `diff`, even though they are identical as far as I can tell (so guessing it is an encoding issue). I'll carry on looking into it and if it is due to anything related I'll accept this as the answer, as I'm sure you've pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how this is necessarily the "opposite"? I've updated my answer to try to clarify.

Comment: Because the FTP process is introducing those conversions. Even if done silently, you would expect this to cause differences in the files *after* they have been uploaded. In this application, there are no differences after the files have been uploaded. The differences are showing *before* anything is done with the FTP client. Clearly the FTP client is doing something with the encoding, but I can't fathom what it is. `file1.html` hasn't been modified, but `file2.html` has. So how can that "fix" it - or make the files the same as far as `diff` is concerned? It's an interesting one for sure!

Comment: To clarify the last comment - `file1.html` has just remained on the server and hasn't gone through the FTP process. `file2.html` has gone through FTP (download locally, re-upload and overwrite original on server). So what I'm trying to establish is how the FTP process is making `file2.html` equivalent to `file1.html` which it hasn't even seen!

Comment: If you FTP `file1.html` instead do you get the same result (my guess is that you won't)? Your `diff` output is consistent with there being just a difference in the whitespace (line-endings), which is resolved initially with the `-w` flag. Depending on the contents of the file, if there was a difference in the encoding then you would expect quite different output. To confirm exactly what is going on you would need to check with a hex editor on your server at the time the `diff` comparison fails.

Comment: You're correct again in that if I FTP `file1.html` it gives a different result. I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/view-line-endings-in-a-text-file which is useful as I can use `vi` with `:set list` to view the new line characters in the file. Sure enough the encoding changes between `\n` and `\r`. So your answer on this is spot on.

Comment: It could be that the download process (`curl`) is also "fixing" line-endings (in a way that is reversed by `ftp`ing it back again). If so, the "real" file on the server would be seen as different to the downloaded one, whereas the re-uploaded one would be the same.  If this is the case, if you were to `ftp` in binary mode, the difference should remain.

Comment: "Mac OS the line-ending char is simply `\r` (ASCII 13)" Sure, classic Mac OS (i.e. 9.x and earlier) used carriage returns, but modern Mac OS (since the switch to BSD-based OS X, and including Sierra) uses the same line feed character  (`\n`) that Linux uses.

Comment: @8bittree Thanks for that - I keep forgetting it changed (I'm not a Mac user)!

Comment: @w3dk regarding character encoding, yes FTP can change it. It's not common because most systems use ASCII or UTF-8 (or UTF-16) for text files, but other encodings are possible. Specifically, our mainframe uses EBCDIC internally and we depend on FTP to convert the text from/to ASCII when moving files to/from the mainframe.

Comment: @KeithDavies Thanks for the info regarding character encoding, I've updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not a well-known phenomenon because almost all modern systems use some form of ASCII or UTF-8. I just have the luck -- good or bad as it might be -- to deal with mainframes using EBCDIC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Don't transfer UTF-16 files in ASCII mode; use binary mode to avoid data corruption here.

FTP's transformation of \r\n to \n will corrupt the remainder of the file if it happens to contain the single character ഊ or the sequence ㄍਰ or many others of the same class.

Please note that this is not an intelligent transformation, and the reverse transformation also exists and covers quite a few more cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , ftp does some encoding changes. Data is transferred from a storage device in the sending Host to a storage device in the receiving Host. Often it is necessary to perform certain transformations on the data because data storage representations in the two systems are different. For example, NVT-ASCII has different data storage representations in different systems. PDP-10's generally store NVT-ASCII as five 7-bit ASCII characters, left-justified in a 36-bit word. 360's store NVT-ASCII as 8-bit EBCDIC codes. Multics stores NVT-ASCII as four 9-bit characters in a 36-bit word. It may be desirable to convert characters into the standard NVT-ASCII representation when transmitting text between dissimilar systems. The sending and receiving sites would have to perform the necessary transformations between the standard representation and their internal representations.(please refer Data representation and storage section of [RFC 765](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc765) for further detail).

Answer (score 2):

The answer I've accepted on this is correct however I'm adding some notes about how I used this information to work out what was going on.

The question uses `file1.html` and `file2.html` for simplicity. In reality `file1.html` represents a "master" copy of a web page downloaded in the past. `file2.html` is the most recent download of the web page content. The intention of the application is to compare the master copy of the file, against the latest version (`diff file1.html file2.html`).

*There are hundreds of these files in the real application.*

What I'd done when creating the master files was to download all a set of `file1.html`-equivalents on to my desktop. I then re-uploaded them via FileZilla into a "master" directory on the server. This was done some time ago (about 1st March) and I hadn't thought of this until realising what had happened.

**Uploading through FileZilla from a Mac has introduced changes in the new-line character, as described in the accepted answer**. Specifically it's using `\r` whereas on the Linux (centOS) web server, it's using `\n`.

So now when I `diff file1.html file2.html` it was saying the files are different. This is because at this point there are 2 different new line characters between the files: `\r` in `file1.html` and `\n` in `file2.html`

What I was then doing was downloading `file2.html` and re-uploading (overwriting) it from my desktop to the server with FileZilla. **This is the point where I posted the original question.**

As the answer suggests, there is a character encoding difference until `file2.html` is uploaded. At this point the files become the same because they have both gone through the same process. From my perspective it was as if merely uploading `file2.html` "fixed" the problem, but couldn't understand why.

I could determine which files were using which new line characters using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/view-line-endings-in-a-text-file

My solution to the whole problem is to not download anything through FTP - as this was merely being used to examine the files - and rather use `cp` on the server when creating the "master" directory of files. Because this is all done on Linux there are no differences in the new line characters, the copy of each file means they are always using `\n`

Basically the solution to this problem is that the new line character has to be the same between files otherwise `diff` will flag them as being different, but the output it gives is not helpful in showing you *what* that difference is, since these characters are "invisible" when the file is displayed (unless you use something like on the link above to show them in an editor).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see how it fits together now. Note that if you FTP in "binary mode" (as it would do by default for images etc. anyway) then there is no "conversion", it is transferred byte for byte. Note also, that this has nothing to do with [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) - that is something entirely different. In ASCII transfer mode the EOL characters are literally being changed, the file's character encoding does not change in this instance (as you noted, "us-ascii" before and after the transfer).